# JSON value is converted to unicode - python

Tags: python, json, testing, automation, python-appium

My current Python Appium test automation framework reads data from JSON file using the **json.load()**

The value **"Ελλάδα"** stored in JSON is converted to **"Î•Î»Î»Î¬Î´Î±"** when **json.load()** method is called.

Pleases point me to a solution were I can maintain the the actual string value **"Ελλάδα"**

**JSON data in testdata.json**

```
{
    "country" : {"country_name" : "Ελλάδα"}
}
```

**JSON load in .py file**

```
with open(file_location) as test_data_obj: 
    pytest.data = json.load(test_data_obj)
```

*This prints out "Î•Î»Î»Î¬Î´Î±"*

```
print(pytest.data["country"]["country_name"])
```

Comment: Can you provide any reproduce-able code?

Comment: Your code (which you didn't post) has a bug. Python 3 strings are Unicode. This page is UTF8, just like 99.9% of web pages. What you posted is what you'd get if you tried to read this page as if it was Latin1 - the bytes that represent a single character in UTF8 were treated as individual characters

Comment: Did you try opening a text file with a hard-coded encoding? Did you use Python 2 instead of 3?

Comment: To get what you posted I'd have to write `"Ελλάδα".encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')` in Python.

Comment: Very strange i am exactly getting what is intended, somehow your code is not actually reproducing the problem that's because this webpage has changed the character encoding which are are copying from the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `with open(file_location,encoding='utf-8')`. For whatever reason, your system uses Latin 1 as the default encoding instead of UTF8.

The file is fine. This page, like 99.9% of web pages is UTF8. That's why you were able to write Ελλάδα without any problem.

Python 3 strings are Unicode too. If you type `"Ελλάδα"` in a Python console you'll get the string back.

To get what you posted I had to decode the bytes using `latin-1` :

```
>>> "Ελλάδα".encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')
'Î\x95Î»Î»Î¬Î´Î±'
```